# How to schedule Spark SQL code in Oozie

Tags: scala, hive, oozie

I have written Spark Sql using scala and HiveContext but I don't know how to schedule it in Oozie. 
[N.B. I am very new in Spark and Scala]

Comment: Are you able to run  the code using spark submit

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge you have now able to run the code using spark-submit.

Follow the below link 
[Unable to run example spark job with oozie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36984908/unable-to-run-example-spark-job-with-oozie)

look into spark oozie action and job properties